# how to migrate Mongo Ruby Driver from 1.9.2 to 1.12.5 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rubygems

I use bundle, and when I wrote

```
bundle install
```

> Using mongo 1.9.2
>   Bundle complete! 24 Gemfile dependencies, 57 gems now installed.
>   Gems in the group production were not installed. 
>   Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/gems.

Next I wrote

```
bundle update mongo
```

> Bundle updated!
>   Gems in the group production were not installed.

How update mongo gem to version 1.12.5?

GemFile

```
gem 'mongo'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
bson (1.9.2)
bson_ext (1.9.2)
      bson (~> 1.9.2)
mongo (1.9.2)
      bson (~> 1.9.2)
mono_logger (1.1.0)
```

and `bson_ext` didn't update too

Comment: What is in `Gemfile` related to mongo?